# Trigger can not works - ora-04091 tabla is muting

Tags: ora-04091

Hy,
I'm beginner in oracle :)

I would like to write a trigger what is watch some record in my AAAA table and if somebody modify some record trigger going to insert into another (BBBB) table the date of modification and modified value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST
AFTER INSERT ON AAAA FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_timestamp timestamp;
   BEGIN
        SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) INTO v_timestamp FROM X.AAAA;
        INSERT INTO BBBB values(:new.a,v_timestamp);
   END;
```

If I try to modify a value in AAAA I get 3 exceptions:

- ora-04091
- ora-06512
- ora-04088